# 404 Error Apache Tomcat 7 running JSP file from Eclipse Juno IDE

Tags: eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I am using Tomcat 7 on the Eclipse IDE to run a JSP file.

It was working fine 2 days ago but now when I'm running my file a 404 Error is showing up:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /

type Status report
message /
description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.34
```

I figured that the server is working fine as it would not give me the error if it wasn't responding. The port I'm using for Tomcat is 8089. Can the reason be that maybe Eclipse is trying to use another port instead of the one I set for the server?

What can I do to run my file without having this error?

Comment: You thus opened `http://localhost:8089` directly instead of opening the JSP file in the deployed webapp context something like as `http://localhost:8089/somecontext/page.jsp`, right?

Comment: no I just run the file from eclipse.. and then I also tried in the browser: http://localhost:8089/jsp/getcount.jsp where getcount is the name of my jsp file

Comment: What error exactly do you get when you invoke the JSP directly? In any way, reading the server log in Eclipse console may give clues (e.g. is the `/jsp` project properly deployed on exactly that context path?)

Comment: How can I read a server log? And what does it mean? I'm still completely new sorry

Comment: Uh. In the right bottom section of Eclipse, you see some tabs. Click the tab which says *Console*. That's the server log. It contains at least information and possible warnings/errors which is printed during server's startup.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, when you're testing a webapp project, eclipse won't adding the full path to the JSP page you want to access and try to connect to http//localhost:8080/YOURPAGE.jsp, this is problematic as the context is missing.

Why are you using port 8089 and not 8080?

It is possible that the context is missing in the tomcat server.xml, do you have a line similar to this?

```
<Context docBase="WebProject" path="/WebProject" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:LoginServlet"/></Host>
```